# jQuery - getting error for square brackets in name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I know there are already a lot of posts in SO regarding this issue. But none of them works for my case.

I've multiple  select inputs with the following naming format:

```
select name="violationCategory[${theCount.count-1}].subCategory"
```

which translates to something like:

```
select name="violationCategory[0].subCategory"
select name="violationCategory[1].subCategory"
.. so on
```

I've to apply a particular class on these select inputs if some condition is fulfilled.
So, I try replacing the square brackets with something like this:

```
if(key.indexOf("[") >= 0){
        key = $.trim(key).replace("name=^[","name=^\\[");
        key = $.trim(key).replace("].","\\]."); 
        alert(key);
        $("#" + formId + " select[name=" + key + "]").addClass('inputBoxError');                            
    }
```

The alert prints:

```
violationCategory[1\].subCategory]
```

and I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #referralViolationForm select[name=violationCategory[1\].subCategory]
```

When I change the code to:

```
key = $.trim(key).replace("].","\].");
```

alert prints:

```
violationCategory[1].subCategory]
```

and I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #referralViolationForm select[name=violationCategory[1].subCategory]
```

So, basically it works neither ways.

Can anyone help me out as to how to escape the square brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attribute value should be wrapped within `""`, there is no need to escape the `[` or `]`

```
$('#' + formId + ' input[name="' + key + '"]').addClass('inputBoxError');
```

So the translated selector should be

```
$('#myform input[name="violationCategory[1].subCategory"]').addClass('inputBoxError');
```

Update 
You need to select a `<select>` element, then you need to change the element selector `input` to `select` like `$('#' + formId + ' select[name="' + key + '"]').addClass('inputBoxError');`

Comment: +1 though But i guess OP is talking about select inputs so `select[name="violationCategory[1].subCategory"]'` ??

Comment: Thanks for the input. Changing the position of the single quotes worked for me:$("#" + formId + " select[name='" + key + "']").addClass('inputBoxError');

Comment: (very sorry about double rollback - mistakenly thought *someone else* had monkeyed with your post)

Answer (score 1):

Special characters need to be escaped by `\`. Which needs to be escaped as well, so - here's an example to deal with your case: http://jsfiddle.net/tb2cW/1/

And here's the list of characters in need of escaping: `~!@$%^&*()_+-=,./\';:"?><[]{}|` and `